# Spring with Hibernate- how to pass schema name dynamically

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using spring-Hibernate DAO Layer, i have created spring configuration file having data source and all the hbm xml list and each hbm is mapped with the table as 
table ="schema1.table1"

We have another schema say prodSchema in production, i want to know how to pass schema name dynamically by using propfile etc.to the hbm file so that in runtime i can change.

Answer (score 0):

Java annotation only supports compile time constants. i.e. you cannot put variable in annotation parameter.
REf : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28

Your situation is common to most of the project and developer. I generally use external database configuration file, where I put the connection parameters, schema and credentials. This file is created on each environment once and remains unchanged until there is any change in DB server.

General Hibernate Property for quick reference.

> **hibernate.connection.driver_class** : JDBC driver class
>
> **hibernate.connection.url** : JDBC URL (may contain schema)
>
> **hibernate.connection.username** : database user
>
> **hibernate.connection.password** : database user password
>
> **hibernate.default_schema** : Qualify unqualified table names with the
> given schema/tablespace in generated SQL. e.g. SCHEMA_NAME (use this
> if you don't specify in JDBC URL)